# Matt phoned while we were having dinner. (who did Matt phone?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **Matt phoned while we were having dinner.**

Is it true that we can't say who Matt phoned?

1 version. Matt could phone them while they were having dinner.

2 version. Matt could phone from their house to someone.

Right?

Comment: We don't have sufficient information to decide.

Comment: Common sense and experience would lead most people to assume the former. Then there's always something called context which clears up any waft of ambiguity.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, If there was the latter, there would be other tense or formulation? What kind of?

Comment: We would know that Matt was in the same room or house as the people having dinner.

Comment: The default interpretation would be 'a phone call came through from Matt' unless it had been previously mentioned that Matt needed to make a phone call to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without context** the reader cannot know whether it was Matt's call that interrupted a meal nor where the call was made. The most likely assumption in descending order is:

> 1. Matt phoned (from work) while we were having dinner.

Matt phoned from work while we were having dinner [at home].

> 2. Matt phoned  while we (i.e Matt and us] were having dinner.

We were all having dinner when Matt made a phone call [to someone].

Answer (score 1):

*To phone* is usually a transitive verb.

> Matt called me yesterday.

When it's not, as in your sentence, the context is supposed to help in identifying the recipient. If there is no context, we may only speculate.

> Matt phoned (us/me) while we were having dinner.

> Matt phoned (someone else who wasn't with them at the time) while we were having dinner.

I think most people, including me, would lean towards the former.

Comment: If I understand you right, native speakers would lean towards the former because "to phone" is usually transitive verb and from the sentence we know only about "them" who had dinner. If the previous sentence was information about someone else who waited a call, native speakers would lean towards the latter. Is it right interpretation?

Comment: @Sergei I am not a native speaker, but the former feels more likely: their dinner was punctuated by a call. Otherwise it has to be known whether Matt was with them. That said, it doesn't matter much: it seems to be a basic grammatical exercise rather than an excerpt from a well-thought story.